# Spring MVC RequestMapping ParamRequest collection/array

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, request

I have a @Controller with a @RequestMapping functions that accept collections.

Imagine something like:

```
requestHandler(Collection<Long> param){
   ...
}
```

This mapping only matches when I send requests such as:

```
http://www.domain.com/mapping/funct?param=1&param=2&param=3
```

I'd like to match it as well when I send a comma sepparated value:

```
 http://www.domain.com/mapping/funct?param=1,2,3
```

Is there a way without using .split ? I'd like it to be automatically parsed to a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write a custom [`Converter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Converter-API) and [register it in your Spring MVC context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-FormattingConversionService).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to access all query parameters and parse according to your needs in this type of scenarios

You should have access to the requests query string via request.getQueryString().

In addition to getQueryString, the query parameters can also be retrieved from request.getParameterMap() as a Map.